# How to display message after all draggable element dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created two exercises in fiddle of drag and drop element. After that I had optimized the code, so code can be reduced. I had merge both fiddle in one and now both are working perfectly in one fiddle.

One fiddle - `*`http://jsfiddle.net/5cZD5/101/`*`
Second fiddle - `*`http://jsfiddle.net/5cZD5/104/`*`

Now fiddle in which both are merged - `*`http://jsfiddle.net/sanjayrathod7/5cZD5/111/`*`

Now I have not idea how to display message in both exercise using making one function.

Please give me suggestions to make it possible.

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are asking about the one function which checks the completion status for both.

So for that what you can do is 
1> Give the id to both the table .
i.e

```
<table width="100%" id="tabel1">
<!-- Your Code -->
</table>

<!-- your Code -->

<table width="100%" id="tabel2">
<!-- Your Code -->

</table>
```

2> Add these two function in script

```
function getParent(draggedElem)
{
var tableId=$(draggedElem).parents("table").attr("id");    
console.log(tableId);
return tableId;
}
function checkCompletionStatus(tableId){

      var isAllFilled = true;
      $("#"+tableId+" .shoppingCart").each(function(){
            if($(this).find('ol .placeholder').length > 0)
            {
                isAllFilled = false;
                return
            }
      });
      return isAllFilled
}
```

3> on each dropped object use it like this

For example , for shoppingCart6

```
var isAllFilled = checkCompletionStatus(getParent(this));
```

Updated

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/5cZD5/113/)

Comment: Can you please update on fiddle cause i dont know where i have to pass this - var isAllFilled = checkCompletionStatus(getParent("shoppingCart6"));

Comment: You are right but if i am droped element in first excersise it shows message but when i am droping element in second excercise message of first exercise hide how will i tackle this?

Comment: Remove this line $("#equal").hide() See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/5cZD5/113/